# How to keep ADF Trigger start time constant

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm using the below bicep to create ADF trigger. Every time I redeploy the trigger, the start time changes as the current timestamp is being used. Is there a way to get the existing startTime value and use it always ?

```
type: 'ScheduleTrigger'
pipelines: [
{
  parameters: {}
  pipelineReference: {
    name: 'string'
    referenceName: 'string'
    type: 'PipelineReference'
  }
}
]
typeProperties: {
  recurrence: {
  frequency: 'string'
  interval: int
  startTime: 'string'
  timeZone: 'string'
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full template to understand more about the issue? @DxG

Answer (score 0):

I've created a data factory with the pipeline reference by referring to the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-bicep?tabs=CLI#review-the-bicep-file) and added the schedule triggers to the data factory as follows.

I created a `param` called `triggerStartTime` and saved the `current time stamp` value in it to maintain the `ADF Trigger` start time constant. Then I put that in the `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers` - `startTime` property/field. As a result, every time I redeploy, the trigger `starttime` has no effect as I have already set it to the current time value.

*I modified your code as below:*

```bash
param  triggerStartTime  string = '2023-17-27T12:00:00Z'
param  triggerName  string = 'trigger${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'
param  interval  int = 15
resource  triggerResource  'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers@2018-06-01' = {
parent: dataFactory
name: triggerName
properties:{
   type: 'ScheduleTrigger'
   pipelines: [
    {
     parameters: {}
     pipelineReference: {
     name: pipelineName
     referenceName: dataFactoryPipeline.name
     type: 'PipelineReference'
    }
  }
]
typeProperties: {
recurrence: {
   endTime: 'string'
   frequency: 'Week'
   interval: interval
   schedule: {
   hours: [
    interval
  ]
   minutes: [
    interval
  ]
   monthDays: [
    interval
  ]
   monthlyOccurrences: [
   {
    day: 'Friday'
    occurrence: interval
   }
]
   weekDays: [
    'Friday'
    ]
 }
 startTime: triggerStartTime
 timeZone: 'utc'
   }
  }
 }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

You can use `if(exists)` conditional function to check if the trigger is existed or not.

```bash
resource  triggerResource  'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/triggers@2018-06-01' = if (exists(triggerResource))
{
parent: dataFactory
name: triggerName
properties:{
  //schedule the trigger code here (Given in the answer)//
   }
}
```

Comment: This works. But I want to use the same template to create multiple triggers. I can't use the same timestamp for all triggers. Is there a way to check if a trigger is created already and then retrieve the triggerStartTime from the existing trigger ?.

Comment: You can check the existence of the trigger using [if](https://oulasvirta.com/2021/10/19/bicep-if-else-operator.html) operator or conditional operators. @DxG

Comment: You can also check [Doc1](https://ochzhen.com/blog/check-if-resource-exists-azure-bicep) & [Doc2](https://arinco.com.au/blog/checking-for-resource-existence-in-bicep/) on how to check the resource existence in bicep. @DxG

Comment: I updated in the answer. Please check. @DxG